# Which statistical test when you have two reviewers (for qualitative scores)?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics, image-processing

Two reviewers (radiologists) assessed image performance (resolution, signal/noise, contrast...) based on a 5-point scale : 1, markedly worse; 2 worse; 3 equivalent; 4 better; markedly better) of 23 patients. The image qualitative scores were statistically analyzed using **Wilcoxon rank** tests (one-sided, the null-hypothesis H0:m≤m0 with m0=3, which represent the “equivalent” quality score).

But **I did TWO SEPARATE Wilcoxon rank test**, one based on the first reviewer results and another one based on the second reviewer results. How can I conduct **one test instead of 2 separate ones?**

*PS: the aim of the study is to know if the new images are better than the old ones, if it's the case the reviewer marked the new image as 4 or 5*

Comment: To clarify, your question is are the scores on average better than "equivalent", but you want a test that answers this question using the scores from both reviewers, right? What software are you familiar with? That may impose a constraint on the approaches you can use.

Comment: Yes exactly!(i think the median is more interesting)I am familiar with R

Comment: All right, I'll adapt a paired ordered example to your case and demo how to go about it with both beta-binomial and multilevel ordinal approaches.

Comment: (Maybe a little bit of clarification, only new images are noted (not old ones) basically radiologists look at the old image and the new image and then mark the new image 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5.)

Comment: I inferred that point, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches I can think of, one simpler than the other: beta-binomial regression and multilevel ordinal regression (a bit more complete approach).

I work with some sample data. `ID` is patient ID, `rev.1`/`rev.2` are reviewer 1/2's scores, discrete bounded 1-5.

```r
head(dat)
#   ID rev.1 rev.2
# 1  1     5     4
# 2  2     5     4
# 3  3     2     5
# 4  4     3     2
# 5  5     5     5
# 6  6     1     1
```

#### First beta-binomial approach

If one asks: what is the chance that on average, the scores were greater than three? I could create binary variables for both reviewers then sum them:

```r
dat$sum <- (dat$rev.1 > 3) + (dat$rev.2 > 3)
head(dat)
#   ID rev.1 rev.2 sum
# 1  1     5     4   2
# 2  2     5     4   2
# 3  3     2     5   1
# 4  4     3     2   0
# 5  5     5     5   2
# 6  6     1     1   0
```

The `sum` variable is simply the number of times a patient had a score above 3. We can think of it as a binomial variable, number of successes out of 2 trials. Given that the patients are different from each other, we could assume beta-binomial instead such that each patient has a unique probability of scoring above 3, but we are primarily interested in estimating the average probability. As opposed to a binomial model where all patients have the same underlying probability.

To run this model, I use the `glmmTMB` package:

```r
library(glmmTMB)
summary(glmmTMB(cbind(sum, 2 - sum) ~ 1, dat, betabinomial()))
#  Family: betabinomial  ( logit )
# Formula:          cbind(sum, 2 - sum) ~ 1
# Data: dat
#      AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
#     50.3     52.5    -23.1     46.3       21 
# Overdispersion parameter for betabinomial family (): 2.25 
# Conditional model:
#             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
# (Intercept)   0.7259     0.3596   2.018   0.0435 *
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Good thing is the model converged. Sometimes, this may not happen. It's likely that one can use a binomial model assuming all patients have the same underlying probability of exceeding 3 on each trial. But the model converged, we may interpret.

The intercept here is .7259 with p-value = .0435. To interpret the intercept, we can apply the inverse-logit link:

```r
plogis(0.7259)
# [1] 0.6739049
```

This means that on average, there was a $67\%$ chance that the patients had a score above 3. The p-value of .0435 suggests that this chance was statistically different from $50\%$ (or null result) at an alpha level of .05. This is the beta-binomial approach to solving this problem.

One could also interpret the "Overdispersion parameter" in the results above using the equation, 1 / (overdisp + 1):

```r
1 / (2.25 + 1)
# [1] 0.3076923
```

This basically implies a 0.31 correlation in the reviewers' scoring of participants above 3.

#### Multilevel ordinal approach

It is proper to treat such ratings are ordinal. In fact, ordinal models are equivalent to Whitney/Wilcoxon-type rank approaches, see: Whitehead, J. (1993). Sample size calculations for ordered categorical data. *Statistics in medicine, 12*(24), 2257-2271. https://hbiostat.org/papers/ordinal/whi93sam.pdf.

So given that you have correlated ordinal data, we can use a multilevel ordinal approach to handle this. I try to motivate this approach briefly.

Ordinal models (or the specific type we will fit) assume the observed ordinal scores are binned reflections of an underlying continuous variable. This continuous variable would be a continuous difference score (new image - old image) in the reviewers' heads but they write down binned variables on paper. If we make certain assumptions about that continuous variable, e.g. we assume the variable follows logistic distribution (looks like the normal distribution) with a mean of zero and a scale of 1, we can actually calculate the cut-points or the points where the original variable was binned. Given your 5-point data, we have 4 cutpoints: 1-2, 2-3, 3-4, 4-5. Specifically, you are interested in the cutpoint from 3-4 on ranks. Our goal will be to test how high/low the cutpoint is. If it is low enough, then most scores in the data were above 3 and we can assume sufficient evidence in the data that the scores were markedly better. The multilevel aspect is because the scores from the reviewers are correlated/paired/matched thus we need to account for that someway.

I next develop the example, and explain what the results yield for us.

First step is to transform the data from wide to long format:

```r
dat.l <- reshape(dat, varying = list(2:3), direction = "long")
head(dat.l[order(dat.l$ID), ])
#     ID sum time rev.1 id
# 1.1  1   2    1     5  1
# 1.2  1   2    2     4  1
# 2.1  2   2    1     5  2
# 2.2  2   2    2     4  2
# 3.1  3   1    1     2  3
# 3.2  3   1    2     5  3
```

Here, each patient is represented by two rows in the data, one per reviewer. Reviewer ID is now the `time` variable. And the scores are the `rev.1` variable. I ensure they are treated as ordinal:

```r
dat.l$rev.f <- as.ordered(dat.l$rev.1)
```

Next, to do the ordinal multilevel model, I use the `ordinal` package:

```r
library(ordinal)
summary(clmm(rev.f ~ 1 + (1 | ID), data = dat.l))
# Cumulative Link Mixed Model fitted with the Laplace approximation
# formula: rev.f ~ 1 + (1 | ID)
# data:    dat.l
#  link  threshold nobs logLik AIC    niter    max.grad cond.H 
#  logit flexible  46   -62.52 135.03 173(521) 1.74e-07 6.3e+01
# Random effects:
#  Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
#  ID     (Intercept) 1.235    1.111   
# Number of groups:  ID 23 
# No Coefficients
# Threshold coefficients:
#     Estimate Std. Error z value
# 1|2  -2.3260     0.6535  -3.559
# 2|3  -1.1843     0.4894  -2.420
# 3|4  -0.9295     0.4614  -2.015
# 4|5   0.2235     0.4084   0.547
```

The model converged, so we focus on the "threshold coefficients". `3|4  -0.9295     0.4614  -2.015` is our target here. The results suggest that the 3|4 cutpoint is low. How low?

```r
plogis(-0.9295)
# [1] 0.2830262
```

Only $28\%$ of the scores are equal to or less than 3, i.e. $72\%$ ($100\%-28\%$) are greater than 3. Additionally, the z-value comparing this $28\%$ to $50\%$ is 2.015, greater than 1.96 suggesting sufficient evidence in the data to conclude that $72\%$ had a score greater than 3, given an alpha-level of .05.

#### Summary

This may be more than you asked for. But I hope both these approaches show how you can answer your question. I would recommend reading up on both models. Simple Google search should reveal useful material. Best.

P.S.: Note how close the z-values are from both approaches. If you ignored the fact that the scores are paired, and simply did a binomial regression (NOT beta-binomial) or an ordinal regression (not multilevel ordinal), results would perfectly align.

Comment: thank you for providing such a developed answer!! I tried to read paper in my field that also used 2 raters to rate qualitative scores, they all seem to compare Quality scores using Wilcoxon rank tests and they don't seem to do separate test for the different raters.i am very confused on how they do it because it seems "easier" to do it that way.